# Dynamically Return a Class of a Type Determined During a Method Call via Class.forName()

Tags: java

I know that I can dynamically determine the return type of a method by passing in a class and then declaring that class as the return type, as in the following example:

```
public static <returnType> returnClass dynamicConstructor (Class<returnType> returnClass){
    //Dynamically construct an object using a zero parameter constructor
    return (returnClass) object;
}
```

The code that would be called would be:

```
DynamicConstructor.construct(constructedClass);
```

This code is nice because when you're calling the method in code, it's simple and encapsulated. However, I would like to take it one step further and make the parameter a string containing the full class name, then have the method determine the type of the object via `Class.forName(className)`. The trouble with this is that I can't figure out how to return the type as determined later on. Using method overloading, the code I have is:

```
public static ?????? dynamicConstructor (String className){
    try {
        return dynamicConstructor(Class.forName(className));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find class at path " + classPath);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea what to put in the part labeled `??????`. I want to be able to somehow reference the class determined by `Class.forName(className)`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible to *create* an instance of the class from the class name (as long as you have a zero-arg constructor), but if the only place the class name is stored is in a String, then there's no way to determine the type to return. So your method signature would be

```
public static Object dynamicConstructor(String)
```

which is probably not very useful or what you want.

So the short answer is, **no, this is not possible**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I decided to take a two-step approach and dynamically create the class in an encapsulated method (which handles any exceptions), resulting in `DynamicConstructor.construct(DynamicClass.find(className));`